# How to drive a 6v relay using 74ls08 output?

Tags: relay

Im using a 74ls08 and gate ic, and I cant drive a 6v relay by using the output of the 74ls08. In what way can I drive the relay?

Comment: A MOSFET comes to mind. What are you limitations? What's the current needed?

Comment: @winny What kind of MOSFET will I use? I will use a 5v for the ic or maybe 9v if possible.

Comment: Take a look at 2N7002, but there are hundreds of others to choose from.

Comment: @Dexmel - "*I will use a 5v for the ic or maybe 9v if possible*" FYI you cannot realistically power that 74LS08 IC *directly* with 9V, if that is what you meant. You will need to update your question to add *lots* more context and detailed information about your project, your constraints (cost, size, power sources etc.), and your existing circuit design, if you want more detailed answers.